# How to mock a function to test persist into database by PHPunit in Symfony

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

this is first time to create unit test by PHPunit to test my business model of my web application. I was confused to mock my class which is used to persist entity. Here is the function of newUser().

```
class AccountBM extends AbstractBusinessModel {

    public function newUser(Account $account) {
        $salt = StringHelper::generateRandomString ( "10" );
        $account->setUsername ( $account->getEmail () );
        $invitation_code = hash ( 'md5', $account->getEmail () );
        $account->setInviationCode ( $invitation_code );
        $account->setPassword ( $this->encoder->encodePassword ( $account->getPassword (), $salt ) );
        $account->setSalt ( $salt );
        $this->persistEntity ( $account );
        return $account;
    }
}
```

Then, I try to create a test unit for this fucntion testNewUser()

```
 public function testNewUser() {
        $account = $this->newAccountEntity ();

        $account_bm =$this->getMockBuilder('AccountBM')
                    ->setMethods(array('newUser'))
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->getMock();
        $account=$account_bm->newUser($account);

        // compare setter value with saved entity
        $this->assertEquals ( 'test@test.com', $account->getEmail () );
        $this->assertEquals ( '123456789', $account->getPhone () );
        $this->assertEquals ( '987654321', $account->getMobilePhone () );
        $this->assertEquals ( 'Mr', $account->getTitle () );
        $this->assertEquals ( 'test', $account->getFirstName () );
        $this->assertEquals ( 'test', $account->getLastName () );
        $this->assertEquals ( 'male', $account->getGender () );
        $this->assertEquals ( '1', $account->getCompanyLogo () );
        $this->assertEquals ( AccountType::IDS, $account->getUserType () );
        $this->assertEquals ( RegionType::NCN, $account->getRegion () );
        $this->assertEquals ( hash ( 'md5', $account->getEmail () ), $account->getInviationCode () );
        $this->assertEquals ( hash ( 'sha256', $account->getSalt () . "test" ), $account->getPassword () );
    }

public function newAccountEntity() {
        $account = new Account ();

        // set account
        $account->setEmail ( "test@test.com" );
        $account->setPassword ( "test" );
        $account->setPhone ( "123456789" );
        $account->setMobilePhone ( "987654321" );
        $account->setTitle ( "Mr" );
        $account->setFirstName ( "test" );
        $account->setLastName ( "test" );
        $account->setGender ( "male" );
        $account->setCompanyLogo ( "1" );
        $account->setUserType ( AccountType::IDS );
        $account->setRegion ( RegionType::NCN );
        return $account;
    }
```

But its seems not going to mock the method "newUser" and its not working on my entity. is there anything wrong with test codes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your question:**

Mocked methods are not the methods you want to test but the methods you **do not** want to test. In your code, you are creating a mock object of the class you want to test (which is totally fine though you usually mock dependent classes you do not want to test) and tell the mock object, that `newUser()` is a method you want to mock.

Instead, you want to test `newUser()` and probably want to test `persistEntity()`:

```
$account_bm =$this->getMockBuilder('AccountBM')
            ->setMethods(array('persistEntity'))
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
$account=$account_bm->newUser($account);
```

You might also want to go through PHPUnits Documentation about mock objects:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

---

**Second, a few tips for developing with PHPUnit:**

In your test you have quite a lot of assertions. The best case scenario ist to have only one assertion per test and PHPUnit actually helps you with that quite nicely, because it is able to compare pretty much everything. So instead of asserting every single value of you object, you can just assert one object with the other and PHPUnit will show you the differences if those objects are not equal.

Plus, you might even want to leave out some information in your entity you do not need. Your database might need a first and a last name, but your method doesn't so your test also doesn't. You won't have to write that much code and it's more readable.

But that's not all, assertions can also be done with mocked methods.

Try your test like this:

```
public function testNewUser() {
    // this is the entity for the method
    $account = new Account();
    $account->setEmail ( "test@test.com" );
    $account->setPassword ( "test" );

    // this is how the entity should look like when it's done
    $expectedAccount = new Account ();
    $expectedAccount ->setEmail ( "test@test.com" );
    $expectedAccount ->setInviationCode ( md5("test@test.com") );
    // changes needed, how does your encoder create the password hash?
    // Or even better: Also mock your encoder, you don't want to test it here
    $expectedAccount ->setPassword ( "test" );
    // As this is a random value, you might want to mock it as well
    // mock a static call
    $expectedAccount ->setSalt ( "10" );

    /** @var AccountBM|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $account_bm */
    $account_bm = $this->getMockBuilder('AccountBM')
        ->setMethods(array('persistEntity'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    $account_bm->expects($this->once())
        ->method("persistEntity")
        ->with($expectedAccount);

    $account_bm->newUser($account);
}
```

You could now assert the returned entity with `$expectedEntity`, but I left that out to show you, that **expecting** a method to be called **with** specific parameters will already trigger an assertion.

As you will see, the above test will fail and show you which properties are wrong. Why is this the case?

Well there are two `ToDo`s marked: Two of your values are generated by methods outside of your class, which should be mocked. Those are `$this->encoder->encodePassword()` and `StringHelper::generateRandomString()`.

So create a mock object for the `encoder` and to mock a static method you put it in a separate method in `AccountBM` to wrap it:

**AccountBm**

```
public function newUser(Account $account) {
    $salt = $this->generateSalt("10");
    $account->setUsername ( $account->getEmail () );
    $invitation_code = hash ( 'md5', $account->getEmail () );
    $account->setInviationCode ( $invitation_code );
    $account->setPassword ( $this->encoder->encodePassword ( $account->getPassword (), $salt ) );
    $account->setSalt ( $salt );
    $this->persistEntity ( $account );
    return $account;
}

public function generateSalt($string)
{
    return StringHelper::generateRandomString ( $string );
}
```

And now mock this method together with the `encoder`:

```
public function testNewUser() {
    $account = new Account();
    $account->setEmail ( "test@test.com" );
    $account->setPassword ( "test" );

    $expectedAccount = new Account ();
    $expectedAccount ->setEmail ( "test@test.com" );
    $expectedAccount ->setInviationCode ( md5("test@test.com") );
    $expectedAccount ->setPassword ( "test" );
    $expectedAccount ->setSalt ( "10" );

    /** @var AccountBM|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $account_bm */
    $account_bm = $this->getMockBuilder('AccountBM')
        ->setMethods(array('persistEntity', 'generateSalt'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    // mock the wrapper for the static method
    $account_bm->expects($this->once())
        ->method("generateSalt")
        ->with("10")
        ->will($this->returnValue("10"));

    // mock the encoder and set it to your object
    $encoder = $this->getMockBuilder("stdClass")
        ->setMethods(array("encodePassword"))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $encoder->expects($this->once())
        ->method("encodePassword")
        ->with("test", "10")
        ->will($this->returnValue(md5("test10")));
    $account_bm->setEncoder($encoder);

    $account_bm->expects($this->once())
        ->method("persistEntity")
        ->with($expectedAccount);

    $account_bm->newUser($account);
}
```

But the test is still failing - I'll leave it to you to replace the wrong values to check if you have understood how the code works ;-)